# How to copy OpenCV lib from one virtual environment to another?

Tags: python, opencv, virtualenv, python-venv

I have created a virtual environment for project "A", where I installed many packages inside it including OpenCV. On the other hand, I created another virtual environment for project "B". I want to copy the OpenCV package from project A environment to project B.

I used this command `` `sudo cp -r VENV1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/opencv_* VENV2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` `` but when I import the opencv library, it doesn't get imported.

So, is there a way to copy only 1 package from one environment to another without any installation or download?